# How to set --runtime nvidia in YAML file of k3s pod deployment for a GPU application?

Tags: kubernetes, gpu, nvidia-jetson, k3s

Jetson Xavier NX

I want to run a GPU program in a k3s pod, but it shows the error

```
ImportError: libnppicc.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

it seems it cannot use GPU resource, because when I use docker run --runtime nvidia ... it works. How to set something like "--runtime nvidia" in the YAML for k3s deployment?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this article: https://dev.to/mweibel/add-nvidia-gpu-support-to-k3s-with-containerd-4j17

--- Below does not work - the download link is broken ---

**1. First configure the containerd to use the nvidia-container-runtime plugin**

```
$ sudo wget https://k3d.io/usage/guides/cuda/config.toml.tmpl -O /var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/etc/containerd/config.toml.tmpl
```

**2. Install NVIDIA device plugin for Kubernetes**

```
$ cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: helm.cattle.io/v1
kind: HelmChart
metadata:
  name: nvidia-device-plugin
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  chart: nvidia-device-plugin
  repo: https://nvidia.github.io/k8s-device-plugin
EOF
```

Reference: https://itnext.io/enabling-nvidia-gpus-on-k3s-for-cuda-workloads-a11b96f967b0

Comment: I got the error when running 
```
$ sudo wget https://k3d.io/usage/guides/cuda/config.toml.tmpl -O /var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/etc/containerd/config.toml.tmpl
```
```
--2021-12-19 13:08:03--  https://k3d.io/usage/guides/cuda/config.toml.tmpl
Resolving k3d.io (k3d.io)... 2606:4700:3031::6815:3dcc, 2606:4700:3036::ac43:d673, 104.21.61.204, ...
Connecting to k3d.io (k3d.io)|2606:4700:3031::6815:3dcc|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2021-12-19 13:08:04 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: Sorry, you are right, the link is broken. Try this article instead: https://dev.to/mweibel/add-nvidia-gpu-support-to-k3s-with-containerd-4j17